# Combine JsonPath with Jackson's JsonProperty for nested nodes?

Tags: json, jackson, pojo, jsonpath

I have the following JSON file (simplified, actually contains more fields, nested and unnested):

```
{
    "name": "Foo"
    "age":
    {
        "years": 29
        "months": 11
    }
}
```

And I have a Java POJO for the above, which only consists of `Name, Years` and `Months`. My question is, is there any way that we can combine `JsonPath` with Jackson's `@JsonProperty` annotation to fetch the nested fields without doing one of the more complicated approaches like this: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-nested-values ? Something like

```
class Person
{
    @JsonProperty("$.name")
    String name;

    @JsonProperty("$.age.years")
    Integer years;

    @JsonProperty("$.age.months")
    Integer months;

    //Setters, getters
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I am also looking for this, did  you find a solution?

Comment: @eddie-ryan Nope. Ultimately, due to time pressure, I ended up writing out an explicit `ObjectMapper` for this scenario.

Comment: I am looking for this too. No takers?

Comment: This question is three years old, no update on this?
I could find this: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath
This is mainly useful for when we want to unmarshall the json string. I need something like this to use in the @JsonProperty in my dto so my json in the RequestBody can get mapped correctly.